# Repeat Keys on Partition Decrypt Screen Excessively High

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard

I have a fully encrypted Ubuntu partition I just installed through the 18.04 LTS USB installer. The repeat keys setting on the screen to decrypt the partition (after selecting Ubuntu on Grub2 but before I login to Ubuntu) is extremely high, to the point where entering the password correctly is very hard and takes multiple attempts every time.

I have tried changing the repeat keys setting under universal access after logging in, but even disabling repeat keys on that screen doesn't effect the decrypt partition process, it still repeats. Is it possible to slow or disable repeat keys on this particular screen?

Comment: is it the same if you try a different keyboard?

Comment: Yeah, it's keyboard dependent. I tried using my desktop's keyboard and the issue vanished. It could be a driver issue? Maybe before it can access the full OS files it's using some old driver. Strange it doesn't happen with Grub command line. It's got to be an issue with cryptsetup specifically. If I boot without the GUI the command line has the same issue for that input.

Comment: The keyboard is the inbuilt keyboard for an ASUS VivoBook F510QA. I'd think it was a problem with the keyboard except it only happens on this one particular input. Grub and Ubuntu (and the Windows system I have dual booting) work fine, but typing on this one input is crazy.